# Php. Вызов метода прародителя

Tags: php, ооп

Ситуация:

```
class A extends etc {
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        //...
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        //...
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        //...
    }
}
```

мне нужно чтобы в С выполнился метод init() но так, чтобы не выполнялся parent::init() (метод родителя), но выполнялись все остальные init() по цепочке наследования.

т.е. выполнился метод init() в С а потом в А и дальше все по цепочке.
как мне пропустить выполнение метода init() в B не изменяя его?

UPDATE: забыл важную деталь. нам не известно название класса прародителя

UPDATE 2: Почему вообще появилась такая идея: [Php. Модификация логики класса при инициализации и родителях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628145/php-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%85)

Comment: Лучше скажите, зачем вам это

Comment: Можно вызвать `A::init()`, однако, не стоит классу `C` знать о деталях структуры иерархии.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557608/how-do-i-get-a-php-class-constructor-to-call-its-parents-parents-constructor
тут еще пример, где ты передаешь параметр дополнительный, через который решаешь какие отцовские методы использовать

Comment: то-есть 
`public function init($bypass = false)
    {
        parent::init();
         if (!$bypass) {
           //..
        }
    }`, а в классе  `С` передаешь параметр, что не хочешь его использовать `$bypassPapa = true;
        parent::init($bypassPapa);`

Comment: @Oleksandr, вы предлагаете изменять метод родителя, а это по условиям задачи нельзя делать.

Comment: @Станислав там вроде бы написано не выполнять?
в моем примере он конечно выполняется, но только продолжает цепочку, а его дополнение к методу игнорируется.

Comment: @Oleksandr, читайте последний абзац вопроса: "как мне пропустить выполнение метода init() в B **не изменяя** его?"

Comment: Одному мне кажется, что нужно **просто наследовать C от A** а не городить магию на пустом месте?

Comment: но ведь в классе B есть тоже методы? они нужны. нужно просто пропустить init() в родителе. но выполнять все остальные. изменять родителей мы не можем и ничего не знаем о тех от кого унаследован родитель

Comment: @WebCoder, кто сказал вам, что эти методы будут работать корректно, если вы пропустили инициализацию? А после следующего обновления пакета в `vendor`?

Comment: @vp_arth сказал я. я поставлю приложение туда где никто никогда не запустит сomposer update

Comment: Тогда возьмите да и перетащите класс B к себе, да поправьте что нужно.

Comment: Упаси Боже заниматься сопровождением такого кода. Вам на code review нагоняя тряпкой не дадут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не отвлекаясь на порицание автора за плохую архитектуру,
вариант с использованием [get_parent_class](http://php.net/get_parent_class):

```
class C extends B {
    public function init()
    {
        $grandPa = get_parent_class(get_parent_class($this));
        $grandPa::init();
    }
}

$c = new C;
$c->init();
```

Работает в [php>=5.3](https://3v4l.org/geFXv)

---

Никто не может гарантировать корректную работу, поскольку разработчик класса B, наверняка рассчитывал на то, что метод инициализации будет вызван.

Задайте себе вопрос, зачем вам нужен неинициализированный класс `B` и можете ли вы наследовать свой класс напрямую от `A`?

---

Второй вопрос, который стоит задать: почему возникла необходимость в пропуске метода?

Вероятно, автор класса `B` позволил себе некоторые сторонние эффекты в этом методе, например, вывод.

Тогда мы можем попробовать исключить эти сторонние эффекты:

```
  public init() {
    ob_start();
    parent::init();
    $output = ob_get_clean();
  }
```

Comment: автор для того и спросил - чтобы в том числе понять: может проблема в архитектуре. изменять родителей я не могу. они в vendor

Comment: Чего это вы о себе в третьем лице? Кто автор?

Comment: я ответил под вопросом в коментах. зачем мне класс B неинициализированный? а с чего Вы решили что он такой. я просто изменю инициализацию в своем методе класса C который сделает все что было в классе B но слегка модифицирую

Comment: Вы смешиваете ответственность. За инициализацию членов, которые вносит класс `B` отвечает класс `B`. А что делать с приватными членами? А если реализация изменится после очередного `composer update` будете заново всё приводить в соответствие?

Comment: я ж вам ответил уже в коментах под вопросом. приложение будет без composer update. там вообще не будет ssh

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю смысл утверждения `изменять родителей я не могу. они в vendor`

Comment: Да и чего демагогию-то разводить? Давайте под ответом лучше обсуждать ответ. В этом ответе рабочее решение вашей проблемы. Чем оно вас не устраивает?

Comment: я задаю вопросы не сколько для того чтобы "выполнить задачу" сколько для "понять как поступают люди нормальные программисты в таком случае") вот на этом вопросе я понимаю что меня клонит куда-то не туда. но меня учили не трогать vendor. понятно что я могу класс утянуть к себе и делать с ним все что хочется. я так понимаю обращаться к прародителям не правильно. огромное спасибо за терпение и диалог

Comment: Если бы вы указали более конкретные данные, что за иерархия, что необходимо изменить, тогда можно было бы что-то посоветовать. Думаю стоит создать отдельный воспрос для этого.

Answer (score 3):

Три варианта:

а) Обращаться к методу дедушки напрямую:

```
class A extends etc {
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        //...
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        //...
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public function init()
    {
        A::init();
        //...
    }
}
```

б) Использовать `call_user_func()` в целом в том же коде.

в) Использовать `ReflectionMethod::invoke`, вынеся логику вне классов. Они будут выглядеть у вас как в вашем примере кода, а уже в использовании их в коде будет конструкция вида:

```
$С=new С();
$reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod(get_parent_class(get_parent_class($С)), 'init');
$reflectionMethod->invoke($С);
```

Но вообще есть еще и четвертый вариант, самый верный - это изменить логику вашего приложения, так как с одной стороны, метода, позволяющего обращаться к "дедушке" каким-то нативным способом, в php нет, а с другой стороны все перечисленные выше варианты - жуткие костыли.

Comment: все прочитал, спасибо, но мне бы решение задачи на этапе проектирования класса. решение в runtime при создании экземпляров класса слегка не то что хотелось бы. понимаю что наверное ошибка в структуре/подходе моем. первый раз возникла такая необходимость, наверное я хочу того чего хотеть нельзя/неправильно.. буду думать над 4 вариантом

Comment: @WebCoder да, решение неверное на уровне проектирования, на мой взгляд. А так понятно, что хочется другого варианта :)

Answer (score 2):

Я подозреваю, что должно быть что-то вроде этого...

```
<?php
class A extends etc {
    public function init($pars = array())
    {
        if (!in_array(__CLASS__, $pars)) echo 'A<br>';
        parent::init($pars);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public function init($pars = array())
    {
        if (!in_array(__CLASS__, $pars)) echo 'B<br>';
        parent::init($pars);
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public function init($pars = array())
    {
        if (!in_array(__CLASS__, $pars)) echo 'C<br>';
        parent::init($pars);
    }
}

$t = new C();
$t->init(['B']);
```

Comment: я не могу менять родителей и прародителей. ибо они в vendor

Comment: все эти подробности, а так же более четкую формулировку задачи (вопроса) нужно описывать сразу... тогда вы получите сразу (или очень быстро) решение, которое будет удовлетворять именно потребностям.

Comment: "как мне пропустить выполнение метода init() в B не изменяя его?" - было написано сразу