# Php. Модификация логики класса при инициализации и родителях

Tags: php, ооп

Решил задать еще один вопрос. После вопроса: [Php. Вызов метода прародителя](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628043/php-%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Мне важно понять как поступать правильно.

Допустим есть класс В в vendor (мы его не можем модифицировать).

```
class B extends A
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        // ... code of init() class B
        Helper::addCssClass($this, 'some-class']);
    }
}
```

у этого класса есть много методов. он полностью устраивает. копипастить себе его весь не хочется.

нужно: добавить возможность опционально отключить действие (например Helper::addCssClass()) в инициализации родителя:

я пока пошел путем костыля:

```
class C extends B
{
    public $skipCssClass = false;

    public function init()
    {
        $grandPa = get_parent_class(get_parent_class($this));
        $grandPa::init();
        // ... code of init() class B (copy-paste)
        if (!$this->skipCssClass)
            Helper::addCssClass($this, 'some-class']);
    }
}
```

но мне самому это очень не нравится. если изменится класс В - получится мягко говоря некрасиво.

подскажите

**Как правильно изменить логику инициализации у родителя? И если это делать не правильно, то как правильно?**

Если бы мне нужно было изменить простой метод - вопросов нет. Перекрыл его своим и все. А здесь цепной запуск parent::init(). Нужно и сменить поведение и не зацепить прародителей и чтобы все работало.

Заранее спасибо за терпение и адекватные ответы.

Comment: А декларировать необходимое состояние, например откатить с помощью  `removeCssClass` не вариант? Дайте ссылку на `packagist`, глянуть хоть.

Comment: Вопрос не в cssClass. это выдуманная задача. вопрос в том как мне правильно изменить логику инициализации вендорного класса? (к которому нет доступа), я наичнаю подозревать что это не возможно и вариант только делать свой класс С альтернативу классу В? так?

Comment: Вот и зря выдуманная, дайте нам приближённую к реальной задачу. Очень похоже, что этот вендорный класс недостаточно гибок для решения вашей задачи без костылей. А может и нет. Мы не можем знать наверняка. Этот пакет open-source? Дайте ссылку.

Comment: я не могу дать ссылку на то чего нет. вместо Helper::addCssClass($this, 'some-class']); там могло быть $this->foo(); и я хочу сделать запуск этого метода по условию. не важно что я хочу. могу ли я изменить метод init() класса B? не нарушая цепочку parent::init() и не трогая этот класс (В)